# flutter location plugin repository returns 403

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, location, jcenter

I was working today on the app that uses [location](https://pub.dev/packages/location) plugin, when my builds started to fails.
Here is the message:

```
Plugin project :location_web not found. Please update settings.gradle.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.+.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :location
      > Failed to list versions for com.google.android.gms:play-services-location.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://google.bintray.com/exoplayer/com/google/android/gms/play-services-location/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

Any ideas, or maybe it's Google cloud fault? My location version is `^3.2.4`

Comment: Could you show us your android/app/build.gradle ? What is your version of Flutter ?

Comment: flutter ver. 1.22.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a [maintenance on Bintray](https://status.bintray.com/incidents/4mzph0y8l6hk?u=s94xyn98c71x) which may explain why you're having this problem all of a sudden.

Note that if you're using a version of Flutter > 1.12, you shouldn't have to configure anything in your `build.gradle` file to setup the location plugin, it may be the root cause of your issue.